# Multiple language using unicode

Tags: xetex, unicode, languages

Following is the requirement:

As we know each and every character has some Unicode, so using that I need to print multiple languages in single document, **without specifying which is which**.
Is this possible?
If it is how to do that could any one please provide me Minimum working example, incorporating multiple languages like Chinese, Japanese, Russian, English.

I read about xelatex but I failed to do so.

Comment: I would say that the answer in general is 'no' since different languages can share the same unicode characters.

Comment: I don't think one could guess the correct language based on Unicode points, sure identifying Japanese because of the Kana scripts might be possible, but many languages share their scripts, like almost all western languages use the Roman alphabet. Russian is not the only language using Cyrillic if I'm not mistaken, and Japanese uses Chinese symbols as well.

Comment: Just putting `\selectlanguage{<lang>}` in the code seems to be the better approach.

Comment: If you need to have hyphenation applied properly, the answer is definitely "no".  By default, only English hyphenation will be applied, and that will apply only to languages using the Latin alphabet, and even that incorrectly if the language isn't actually English.